# document.getelementbyid return undefined for input type

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple change password form with some scripts use to validate form. The problem is that the input field with `id=password` is returning undefined when i debug my form. Where am i doing wrong? Any suggestions please.

```
  <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit_pass']))
   {
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
   $confirmpasssword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confirmpassword']);
   if($password==$confirmpasssword)
   {
    $email=$_SESSION['login_email'];
   $insert=("update customers set password='$confirmpasssword' where email='$email'");
   $insert1=mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    echo "<script> alert('Your password is changed');</script>";
    }
   else
   {
    echo "<script> alert('Your password is not changed');</script>";
   }
    }
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(str)
    {
     if (str=="")
      {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
     }
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
       else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
           }
           xmlhttp.open("GET","check_password.php?q="+str,true);
           xmlhttp.send();
                }
            </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
         function pass()
           {
       var cpwd=document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;
       var pwd=document.getElementById("password").value;
      if(pwd==cpwd)
        {
        var t1=document.getElementById('pass').innerHTML="Password Match";
          }
         else
         {
         var t1=document.getElementById('pass').innerHTML="Password does not Match";
        document.form.password.focus();
         }
                }
            </script>



            <div id="password" class="tab-pane fade">

                <form id="form_setup" name="form_setup" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return passvali();">
                    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" bgcolor="#C1C1FF">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center"> <h2>Change Password</h2></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th> Current Password <span style="color:#F00;">*</span></th>
                            <td><input type="password" name="cur_pwd" class="input" id="oldpassword"placeholder="Enter Current Password" onChange="showUser(this.value)" /></td>
                            <td> <span class="st" id="txtHint"></span> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>New Password <span style="color:#F00;">*</span></th>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password" class="input" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th> Confirm Password <span style="color:#F00;">*</span></th>
                            <td><input type="password" name="confirmpassword" class="input" id="confirmpassword" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" onChange="return pass()" /></td>
                            <td><span id="pass" style="color:#F00;"> </span> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit_pass" value="Submit" style="width:80px;" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>


            </div>
```

Comment: declare the script after the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two elements with `id="password"`:

[image]

IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Id needs to be unique. That's true. But even if you have elements declared with same id, document.getElementById('..') would not give you undefined. It's just going to select the very first instance of that object in the DOM.

Comment: @DinoMyte it would if you request the `.value` property of a `<div>`!

Comment: Correct. But the OP mentioned 'document.getelementbyid return undefined'

Comment: @DinoMyte I suspect that they are in fact referring to the value of the `pwd` variable, not the `document.getelementbyid` return.  They are assigning the blame on the wrong statement.  If `document.getelementbyid` actually returned `undefined`, the code would thrown an Exception trying to access the `value` property of `undefined` which it is not.

Comment: That is correct. He needs to check if the property 'value' exists on the selected target.

Comment: @Draco18s yes you are right. the value of pwd is undefined

Comment: @DinoMyte or in this case, properly use one ID per object, because simply checking for the existence of `.value` won't get him a reference to the object he wants.  The error in this case is not checking for null, but rather in that he has the same ID applied to two separate objects and the behavior is not what he desires.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ids called "password", check your code for id to be different

Comment: That doesn't matter. Check the comment posted below to @Draco's answer

Answer (score 0):

There have 2 password ids first is `<div id="password" class="tab-pane fade">` and second is input field, same name id will be one time in one page.

change your `focus()` function code with `document.forms[0].password.focus();`